# Ubuntu Hardy gvfs-fuse-daemon taking 50% of disc space

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-8.04

A 'gvfs-fuse-daemon' filesystem has appeared, which is taking up 50% of my disc space:

```
jhw@jhw:~$ df -h  
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/sda2             5.9G  4.9G  965M  84% /  
varrun                501M  100K  501M   1% /var/run  
varlock               501M     0  501M   0% /var/lock  
udev                  501M   44K  501M   1% /dev  
devshm                501M   12K  501M   1% /dev/shm  
lrm                   501M  1.7M  499M   1% /lib/modules/2.6.24-27-lpia/volatile 
gvfs-fuse-daemon      5.9G  4.9G  965M  84% /home/jhw/.gvfs  
jhw@jhw:~$
```

I'm pretty sure this is a Hardy bug

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/simplebackup/+bug/227753

As the link says, gvfs seems to have decided that one of my network drives is in my root partition, making it think the root partition is full.

Unfortunately none of the solutions in the link work for me. I think this happened when I plugged in a badly formatted USB drive and then didn't unmount it properly. I'm looking for any advice as to how to unmount this gvfs network drive, and free up my disk space.

Thanks!

---

jhw@jhw:~$ gvfs-mount -l
Drive(0): USB Drive

So it is the USB drive ..

jhw@jhw:~$ gvfs-mount -u
jhw@jhw:~$ gvfs-mount -u 0
Error finding enclosing mount: Containing mount does not exist

Do I have the unmount syntax right?

jhw@jhw:~$ gvfs-mount -l
Drive(0): USB Drive

Doh

fusermount -u removes the gvfs entry but doesn't free the space; the entry then reappears on restart

Answer (score 0):

Try `/usr/bin/gvfs-mount --list` and `/usr/bin/gvfs-mount --unmount`.

Or

Try `fusermount -u /home/jhw/.gvfs` (you might need `-z` instead of `-u`).